# Spotfire: is there a (built-in) function to test whether a row is marked?

Tags: spotfire

In a scatterplot, I would like to use the "Line Connection" property to connect only the currently marked data points (= rows) by lines. To achieves this, in principle, I could use the "Order each line by:" setting in "Line Connection" if I manage to assign NULL to all non-marked rows (which would prevent that lines be drawn for such data points). I would use a custom expression for "Order each line by:" like this:

```
If(row_is_marked(), 1, NULL)
```

How can I test whether a row is marked (in the visualization's current marking)? I couldn't find a function like 
`row_is_marked()`.

I know it could be achieved with an IronPython script that creates a 'flag' column in the underlying data table, but that needs quite a bit of setting things up, hard-coding of the data table's name, etc. So, I'm hoping for a simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to check whether a row is marked using calculated value/expression.

What you may want to do instead is to set a limit data from marking (Visualization properties -> Data) to display only marked data for example. Note that you can have multiple marking schemes.

If you need something more complex, you will have to use the workaround you stated in your question (ironpython).